# GNOME Boxes not able to see virtual machines after sleep

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, gnome-shell, libvirt, gnome-boxes

I am having a bit of trouble to solve this issue. I am using `gnome-boxes` to run my Windows virtual machines for my school project purpose. When I boot the system, everything works just fine.

When I type:

```
virsh list --all
```

the output I have at this point would be:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     boxes-unknown                  shut off
 -     win8.1                         shut off
```

When I close the laptop lid to put it on sleep and wake him up. The output is different:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no valid connection
error: Cannot write data: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

So I tried plenty of things, first I have downloaded the latest packages of `gnome-boxes`, `virtlib` and `libvirt-gobject`.

I have tried to reconnect to the hypervisor, which is in this case QEMU, it doesn't work, it says that it fails to reconnect. (I am trying to reconnect with `libvirt`.)

I am out of solution and I believe I am not the only one whom this happens to.